# prove an isomorphism 4

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T : Rn → Rm$ be any linear transformation, and let $S : ker(T )⊥$ to $im(T )$ be the linear transformation from $ker(T )⊥$ to $im(T )$ defined by $S(⃗x) = T (⃗x)$ for all ⃗$x ∈ ker(T )⊥$. Prove that S is an isomorphism.

I'm very confused about this question. to prove an isomorphism we could either choose to proof that dim(source)=dim(target space) or show that it's bijective. I don't know which route to take and how to solve this. is there any way to show that ker(S) is {0}? someone, please guide me as to how I should approach this problem. thank you

Comment: Do you actually read what you have produced?

Comment: Show the bijectivity of $S$. This is really simple. For the injectivity, let $x\in(\ker T)^\perp$ such that $Sx = 0$. What follows then?

Comment: x would then also be in the ker(S)

Comment: Yes, and how is $S$ defined?

Comment: S takes vectors in $x∈(kerT)⊥$ and maps them to the $im(T)$ so 0 is in the im(S) and in the im(T)

Comment: Bot HOW does it take the vectors from $(\ker T)^\perp$ to $im T$?

Comment: by multiplying with the matrix of the transformation? I'm sorry I know I sound really stupid

Comment: Well, yes, and that matrix is $T$. So $Sx = 0$ means $Tx = 0$. Hence...?

Comment: x is in the ker (T)

Comment: Yes! And at the same time in $(\ker T)^\perp$. So?

Comment: $ker(T)$=$(\ker T)^\perp$

Comment: No. You know what $(\ker T)^\perp$ is?

Comment: all the vectors orthogonal to the vectors in the $(\ker T)^\perp$

Comment: No. All the vectors orthogonal to the vectors in $\ker T$.

Comment: sorry that's what i meant

Comment: So if $x\in \ker T$ and is orthogonal to all the vectors in $\ker T$, then it is orthogonal to itself. Right? What can you say now?

Comment: x is the zero vector.

Comment: Bingo! So $S$ is injective. Now the surjectivity.

Comment: for surjectivity can we say that by rank nullity since ker(S) is {0} dim(im(S)=Rm so its surjective?

Comment: Yes, you can use it. But not in the way you did, because it is wrong. Note that $S : (\ker T)^\perp\to im(T)$. Thus, the rank-nullity theorem says that $\dim (\ker T)^\perp = \dim im(S) + \dim\ker(S) = \dim im(S)$. You could use this now for showing that $S$ is surjective, but I recommend to go the usual way. For this, let $y\in im(T)$ be arbitrary. You have to show that there exists $x\in (\ker T)^\perp$ such that $Sx = y$.

Comment: okay. thank you so so much for your help!